# Mention of Dvija in Mahabharat?

Tags: mahabharata

For whom the word Dvija is used in Mahabharat ?

I have heard that in Mahabharat the word Dvijottama (best of twice borns) is used and it is ascribed to Dron.

What is the truth of the word "Dvija" in Mahabharat ?

Comment: Dvi -2 Ja- born This question should be closed because you already have the answer

Comment: @PrasannaR I am not taking about previous births  . I am asking about the word "dwija". It doesn't have anything to do with previous birth.

Comment: I didnt mean previous birth..please refer my first comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [dictionary](https://www.learnsanskrit.cc/index.php?tran_input=dvija&direct=au&script=hk&link=yes&mode=3), **द्विज (dvija)** means **twice-born** i.e. member of the three varnas: Brahmins, Kshtriyas and Vaisyas. The second birth is symbolic when they wear the sacred thread.

Hence, **द्विजोत्तम (dvijottama)** would mean "**best among the twice-born ones**" as explained by Swami Sivananda in [BG 1.7](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=1&field_nsutra_value=7&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1).

In Mahabharata, द्विजोत्तम (dvijottama) is used for Drona but it's not limited to him. We can find it's references for many people at many places as it's not a proper noun but a honorary word. Below are the few  mentions [but there are many others too]:

- Sage Uttanka ~ [Adi Parva, Chapter 3](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs01003.htm)
- Sage Sthūlakeśa ~ [Adi Parva, Chapter 8](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs01008.htm)
- Drona ~ [BG 1.7](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=1&field_nsutra_value=7&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1)
- Parasurama ~ [Udyoga Parva, Chapter 179](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs05179.htm)
- random people in bulk ~ at many places: [ref1](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs13059.htm), [ref2](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs03144.htm)

Answer (score 2):

As per Gita Press's Mahabharata(Complete),Adiparva,khandavadahparv(chapter 221), verse 33, Agni deva is mentioned as dvijaottam in the following verse:

> उपसृष्टं तु तं कृष्णौ भ्राजमानं **द्विजोत्तमम्** ।
> अर्जुनो वसुदेवाश्चा तूर्णमुत्पत्य तस्थतुः ॥

As agni deva came in form of a bramhan

A screenshot for reference from the book I have:

[image]

Comment: It is mentioned after the subhadra vivah part in mahabharata will put refrences in some time

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! Thanks for adding references. We encourage users of this site to back up answers from authentic sources. You may visit [how-to-answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) section to learn more. Also if you need any help, feel free to ping in main chatroom: [Hinduism Chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism)